# try to access qml global variable, but it reports error

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

my code

**AppDelegate.js** for global variables

```
.pragma library

var appDelegate= {}
```

**MyApp.js**

```
Qt.include("AppDelegate.js")



function AppDelegate(){

}


AppDelegate.prototype.doSomething=function() {


    console.log("vvvvvvvvvvvvv")

}
AppDelegate.prototype.doSomething1=function() {


    console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA")

}
//-------------------------------------------------------
function initApp(){


    appDelegate=new AppDelegate()
    appDelegate.doSomething()
    appDelegate.doSomething1()

}
```

**MyApp.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import "MyApp.js" as MyApp


ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    title: "System Dialogs Gallery"
    width: 580
    height: 480

    TabView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 8
        Tab {
            id: controlPage
            title: "File"
            FileDialogs { }
        }

    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        MyApp.initApp()

    }
}
```

it works well and output is

```
qml: vvvvvvvvvvvvv
qml: AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

but if I call from other .js .qml file

**ColorDialogs.js**

```
Qt.include("AppDelegate.js")



function doit(){



    appDelegate.doSomething1()

}
```

**ColorDialogs.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

import "ColorDialogs.js" as ColorDialogs



Item {


    Component.onCompleted: {


        ColorDialogs.doit()

    }
}
```

it reports error:

```
ColorDialogs.js: : TypeError: Property 'doSomething1' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Your comment welcome

----------------------------updated

[image]

Comment: `onCompleted` for your `ColorsDialog` is called before `ApplicationWindow`'s `onCompleted` (assuming FileDialogs and ColorsDialog is the same thing :), so your variable is uninitialized at that point.

Comment: @Sergei Ousynin my code is right, I tested them, onCompleted for your ColorsDialog is called after ApplicationWindow's onCompleted

Comment: well, i tried to reproduced it and here's what I see https://imgur.com/a/E6DQOFq (I changed `FileDialogs` on controlPage to `ColorsDialog` and added logging to `onCompleted`). Maybe you're using ColorsDialog in a different way

Comment: @Sergei Ousynin that is not the key point(please refer to my updated image, ColorsDialog is the second Tabview), the way QML call global var is different from traditional javascript, appDelegate is the global I want to set, but if I call from different javascript file, appDelegate is different

Comment: Have you checked [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html)? (I've never imported variables from other js files, just functions, and had no problems with it)

Comment: @Sergei Ousynin  at least , in file MyApp.js the code:  appDelegate=new AppDelegate() , does not really change the content of appDelegate, that is reason why I call appDelegate.doSomething1() in ColorDialogs.js, it reports TypeError: Property 'doSomething1' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: @Sergei Ousynin yes, my codes follow that standard, I know the url you mentioned

Comment: I put my code project here https://www.kaisatec.com/qtdialogs.zip

Comment: appDelegate is just an empty object until you call `appDelegate = new AppDelegate()`, so the error is kind of expected

Comment: but I call appDelegate.doSomething1() in ColorDialogs.js is after appDelegate=new AppDelegate() in MyApp.js

Comment: `Qt.include()` "copies all functions from the other file into the current file's namespace", maybe that's the issue. Also, why bothering with the variable and prototypes? I don't see the big picture, but you could just declare your doSomething as free functions.

Comment: prototype style is for a big project